# Angular 2: Dynamic ViewChild or dynamic template?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

iam currently building some an app with nested slides. The user can swipe vertical and horizontal.

Works really good so far, but when i change to the second slide i cant acces the active index.

This is my template:

```
<ion-slides #exerciseSlider [options]="exerciseSliderOptions" (ionDidChange)="onExerciseSlideChanged()">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let exercise of workout.exercises; let i = index;">

        <ion-slides #setSlider [options]="setSliderOptions" (ionDidChange)="onSetSlideChanged()">

            <template ngFor let-set [ngForOf]="exercise.sets" let-setNumber="index">

                <ion-slide [attr.data-timer]="exercise.sets[setNumber].duration">
                .....
                </ion-slide>

            </template>

        </ion-slides>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

And here is my code:

```
@ViewChild('exerciseSlider') exerciseSlider:Slides; // Main Slider
@ViewChild('setSlider') setSlider:Slides; // Nested Slider -> there are 3 or more nested slides for each main slide

onExerciseSlideChanged() {
    console.log(this.setSlider);
    let currentIndex = this.exerciseSlider.getActiveIndex();
    console.log("Current index is", currentIndex);
}

onSetSlideChanged() {
    window.clearInterval(this.interval);
    let that = this;
    let exerciseIndex = this.exerciseSlider.getActiveIndex();
    let setSliderIndex = this.setSlider.getActiveIndex();
    console.log(this.setSlider.getActiveIndex());
```

So each exercise have X sets.

I think i have to create the "@ViewChild('setSlider') setSlider:Slides;" dynamically.

Is this right?

The question is: How?

The other solution is to create a  for each slide and load it, when the user slide.

Or is there a bitter way to solve this?

**EDIT:**

I now managed to get a questlist with:

```
@ViewChildren('setSlider') setSliders: QueryList<Slides>;
```

Now all i need is to get an item out of that QueryList.

For Example: setSliders[0] ---> dont work.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no way to create `@ViewChild('setSlider') setSlider:Slides;` dynamically. I don't understand the actual problem you try to solve and therefore don't know what to suggest instead. You can use `@ViewChildren(...)` and subscribe to the variable to get updates about changes. No idea if this helps.

Comment: The problem is, that i cant access the second instance of <ion-slides>, because @ViewChild('setSlider') setSlider:Slides; only give me the first one. 

I need a way to create something unique:

Way 1: I create the setSlider only ounce in a tempalte or something, but dont know how:

Way 2... not sure :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@ViewChildren()` to get all `IonSlides` component instances (you can also query for `'setSlider'` as you currently do) and then just query the result for the one you actually want.

```
@ViewChildren(IonSlides) ionSlides:QueryList<IonSlides>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.ionSlides.toArray().filter(s => s.someProp == someValue));
}
```

Comment: Thanks looks really promising, but when i use it:

@ViewChild('setSlider') setSlider:QueryList<Slides>;

setSlider is undefined. Is it right?

Comment: What do you mean with "when"? It is available when `ngAfterViewInit()` is called and is updated automatically when the content changes.

Comment: I did this: 
    @ViewChildren('setSlider') setSliders: QueryList<Slides>;

and then:

ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.setSliders); // -> QueryList {_dirty: false, _results: Array[0], _emitter: EventEmitter}

console.log(this.setSliders.toArray()); // --> Array[0]

    }

I did some error here i think.

Comment: Seems there is no `Slides` component instantiated in the view. Perhaps not yet. Try `ngAfterViewInit() { this.setSliders.subscribe(x => console.log(this.setSliders.toArray()); }`. This way it prints when the query result changes.

Comment: Hmm, looks like there is no subscribe method. 

I also tried this: 

this.setSliders.changes.subscribe((x): void => {
            console.log(x);
        });

but there is nothing in the console. :(

Comment: Sorry, forgot the changes. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?